# Python for-loop deletion stops halfway

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Just started learning Python today. I'm enjoying it and the docs are as helpful as people say. But there's clearly something I'm not getting about two of Python's idiosyncrasies: those lists and those for-loops.

The result of this code:

```
lets = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']

for j in lets:
    del lets[0]
    print(lets)
```

Is this:

```
['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
['e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
```

Why does it stop at five steps instead of ten (and hence delete all the items)?

Comment: Well you are iterating over a list that you are deleting as you iterate over it. Seems like maybe you don't want to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, you have ten elements in `lets`. Your loop stops at five. After deleting five elements you have five elements left. After the fifth loop, it checks how many elements are in `lets`, sees five, and stops as it has already looped five times.

Comment: Okay, so similarly malformed loops might cause the two to meet somewhere other than the exact middle. I think I understand.

Answer (score 4):

You are modifying a collection as you iterate over it.  This is a huge red flag - never do this.

If you want to fix your above code, iterate over a *copy* of `lets`:

```
for j in lets[:]:
    del lets[0]
```

Or some other object that is of the same length as `lets`, like `range(len(lets))`.

I'll point out that the above is more simply done with `lets.clear()`

Comment: lets.clear() makes sense. This was just a simplification-of-simplification; the original goal had nothing to do with deleting everything from the list. (I actually ran across it by accident when I only wanted to delete a single item but put the instruction into the for look, and then I thought "Wait a minute, I wouldn't expect this behavior...)