# Python "for loop" stops iterating on a list of numbers midway when removing items conditionally from a dictionary

Tags: python, for-loop

The problem relates to finding "Top `k` Frequent Elements" in a list of numbers. My inputs are:

```py
    nums = [0,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,10] 
    k = 3
```

Note that `nums` is in *ascending order*

And my code is

```py
    dic = {}
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        dic[nums[i]] = dic.get(nums[i],0)+1
        if len(dic) > k:
            dic.pop(min(dic,key=dic.get))
    print(dic)
```

The code has a `for` loop that stops after 11 iterations and prints `dic = {2: 2, 3: 4, 4: 3}` whereas the loop is expected to run 24 iterations and produce the desired result `dic = {3: 4, 7: 5, 8: 5}`.

All the discussions on various website pages relate to the mistake of removing items form the same list that the loop is iterating over. For example, these stakesoverflow threads [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54819429/9182826), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22623602/9182826), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54819365/9182826), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6260089/9182826), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70871625/9182826) are all related to deleting/popping/removing items form the same list on which a `for` or `while` loop is iterating on. I am not doing that mistake but still  my `for` loop stops midway.
The thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67715490/for-loop-stops-when-removing-an-item-in-a-seperate-list-python) has a similar headline as mine but the code exhibits that it is doing the same mistake of removing items from the same list of iteration.

Comment: Why do you think the loop stops midway? Print `i` in each iteration, that's an easy way to check if what you say is actually happening

Comment: You’re explicitly removing elements again from your dict. How did you conclude that it’s the loop stopping halfway through, and not just the result of your code running to completion?

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:` or `for index, item in enumerate(list):`

Answer (score 2):

It's not stopping after 11 iterations (if you `print(i, nums[i])` on each loop, you'll see all the loops run as expected).

The problem is that once you reach `k` items with >1 counts, every time it reads a new item, it adds it with a count of `1`, determines the `dict` is too long, and pops off the lowest item, the newly added element with a count of `1`. Then it repeats this when it sees it again, so no new elements are ever added.

I'm assuming your intent (in having all identical elements contiguous) is to be able to eagerly pop off smaller counts of items, but you have to wait for all the duplicate elements to be processed first. It's tricky to get right, and you don't actually need to do it, because the case of counting adjacent duplicates relatively cheaply can be handled quite easily with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) (which we'll use here in roughly the same way the command line utility `uniq -c` works):

```
import itertools

nums = [0,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,10] # Note that nums is in **ascending order**
k = 3
dic = {}

# Iterates over adjacent duplicates; num is the value duplicated, grp is
# an iterator that produces that same value as many times as it appears in the input
for num, grp in itertools.groupby(nums):
    dic[num] = sum(1 for _ in grp)  # Count the items in the iterator, assign to matching key
    # We've got *all* the copies counted, so *now* we can pop off the smallest safely.
    if len(dic) > k:
        dic.pop(min(dic,key=dic.get))
print(dic)
```

Comment: If your real input has truly huge runs of duplicates, you *might* benefit from [a more optimized means of counting the number of items in the grouping iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34404546/364696), but `sum(1 for _ in grp)` is fine for any problem within a few orders of magnitude of the scale of your example.

Comment: For truly huge runs of duplicates, you might want to use exponential searches or some other binary search stuff.

Comment: @KellyBundy: Good point. I guess I should say "for large, but not huge" cases for my suggestion. The algorithm would look *very* different then though, and unlike this approach (which could be tweaked to handle multiple groupings of the same value, and which would work even if the values weren't in proper ascending order), it would be a complete rewrite, and would impose greater restrictions on input organization.

Comment: Yes, would be quite different. I'm actually thinking of divide-and-conquer now, somewhat like [this](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XVFBasMwEKRXvWKhF8uVGztpaQj4C_2A8cFYciJwJCOvoaX0Jb3k0j6qr-lmrZikO7rs7Gg0Yr9-hnc8eHc6fU_YZdvfuzc3HUcoocpVodaETcQT45nwsmC7oMhruIdXjwbw0CCwi6XjIE2bsTVOW7cHH7QJaSqEti098vEptOmg9X1vWkxGbAIqGNEPcieAynbsVPGkhrK8tH7IinrWnIvsqishKc_U495gckUryCU8sD9kwNziEAxOwXF7tJruz2miXMJqBWue_gtLYnnDExG_IGL63c08V9Abx7GkFEOwDhPKKucFxD1c9vEH).